# What's on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that this question was closed for being off-topic:

[How to set my terminal to use solarized palette?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/how-to-set-my-terminal-to-use-solarized-palette)

I can't imagine using Vim without a different colourscheme, and a slightly solarized one is my favourite, and it took me a while to get it working without using gvim.  I ended up with a bash script to set the colours in bash which are then picked up on from within vim with the solarized colourscheme. This is not obvious, certainly not to beginners to bash, vim and custom vim colourschemes.

I've just asked a question which involves the interplay of Gnome and Vim ( [Remapping F1 on vim-gnome](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4651/remapping-f1-on-vim-gnome) ) - is that similarly off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

You're obviously using gnome-terminal *with Vim*, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a Vim question. You're also using Gnome, Linux, GNU libc, a keyboard, a screen, and (probably) a coffee mug with Vim. But that doesn't mean that *all* questions about those subjects are on-topic just because they're being used in conjunction with Vim ;-)

There's definitely a "grey area" of questions that overlap Vim plus $something_else, and often it's just not clear that this is terminal (or OS, WM, etc.) problem from the outset, but in both these cases it seems pretty obvious that it's just a terminal setting.

Your question is reasonable, has an accepted answer, and not spectacularly off-topic, so I see no reason to remove/migrate it now.